# Square bracket notation around variable in cmd / DOS batch scripts

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've seen cmd batch scripts using square notation to surround a variable. For example:

```
@echo off
if [%1]==[] (
echo no parameter entered
) else (
echo param1 is %1
)
```

What is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

it is used for proper syntax. Just imagine, you want to check, if a variable is empty:

```
if %var%== echo bla
```

obviously will fail. (wrong syntax)

Instead:

```
if "%var%"=="" echo bla
```

works fine.

Another "bad thing": you want to check a variable, but it may be empty:

```
if %var%==bla echo bla
```

works well, if %var% is not empty. But if it **is** empty, the line would be interpreted as:

```
if ==bla echo bla
```

obviously a syntax problem. But

```
if "%var%"=="bla" echo bla
```

would be interpreted as

```
if ""=="bla" echo bla
```

correct syntax.

Instead of `"` you can use other chars. Some like `[%var%]`, some use `!` or `.`
Some people use only one char instead of surrounding the string like `if %var%.==.`
The most common is surrounding with `"` (because it will not fail if var contains spaces or an unquoted poison character like &.) ***)**, but that depends on personal gust.

***)** Thanks to dbenham, this is a very important information

Comment: So quotes "" and [] can be used interchangeably for the purposes of empty varaibles? There's no difference? I thought maybe there is some advantage of using [] compared to ""

Comment: @Jim - There is no advantage to using `[%var%]==[value]`. It would work just as well as `]%var%[==]value[` or `XXX%var%==XXXvalue`. There is an advantage to using `"%var%"=="value"` because it will not fail if var contains an unquoted poison character like &.

Comment: @dbenham - however, it *will* fail if `var` contains an unquoted poison character like `"`.  Consider `SET var="foo bar"`, which becomes `if ""foo bar""==""`; which will likely award you a `bar""=="" was unexpected at this time.`...

Comment: @jimbobmcgee - Yes, that is why I always try to keep quotes out of my variable values. If I really want robust code that can handle any content, then I use delayed expansion.

Answer (score 3):

The square brackets are needed to check for blanks because if you use:

```
if %1==[] (
echo no parameter entered
) else (
echo param1 is %1
)
```

Without the square brackets surrounding the variable, it will say

> ( is unexpected at this time

and exit.